# Error in difference between dates in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python

I'm trying to analyze the SLA, considering business hours and days, for operational tasks from a workflow system, extracted from a sheet, but I got an error at the end calc. I would appreciate if someone can help me to identify what to do to solve this.

```
#Importing packages
from business_duration import businessDuration
from datetime import time,datetime
import holidays as pyholidays
import pandas as pd

#Defining business hours
starttime=time(8,0,0)
endtime=time(18,0,0)

#Holidays
holidaylist = pyholidays.Brazil()
unit='hour'

#Importing the data

df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\ricardo.reis\Downloads\BaseTarefasBanco_2m.xlsx')

#Subsetting the interest variables
df_2 = df.loc[:, ["T. Padrão", "Tarefa Padrão", "Cadastramento", "Fim da execução"]]

#Filtering just datatime colums (start time and end time)
df_2_alt = df_2.loc[:, ["Cadastramento", "Fim da execução"]]
df_2_alt

Output:
    Cadastramento   Fim da execução
0   2021-09-29 13:11:11 2021-09-29 13:11:11
1   2021-09-29 13:06:03 2021-09-29 13:06:50
2   2021-09-29 12:15:41 2021-09-29 12:15:41
3   2021-09-29 12:15:41 2021-09-29 12:16:34
4   2021-09-29 12:14:23 2021-09-29 12:16:20
... ... ...
25253   2021-07-28 08:31:50 2021-07-29 16:25:26
25254   2021-07-28 08:26:06 2021-07-29 16:22:26
25255   2021-07-28 08:16:38 2021-07-29 16:14:03
25256   2021-07-28 00:05:43 2021-07-28 09:29:58
25257   2021-07-28 00:05:05 2021-07-28 00:05:43
25258 rows × 2 columns

#Filtering one row for start date to test the calc

startdate = df_2_alt.iloc[[1], [0]]
startdate = startdate.stack()
startdate = pd.to_datetime(startdate, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
startdate

Output: 1  Cadastramento   2021-09-29 13:06:03
dtype: datetime64[ns]

#Filtering one row for end date to test the calc

enddate = df_2_alt.iloc[[1], [1]]
enddate = enddate.stack()
enddate = pd.to_datetime(enddate, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
enddate

Output: 1  Fim da execução   2021-09-29 13:06:50
dtype: datetime64[ns]

#Measuring the SLA for the test variables
sla = businessDuration(startdate,enddate,starttime,endtime,holidaylist=holidaylist,unit=unit)
print(sla)

Output:
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\RICARD~1.REI\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_10084/3998155098.py in <module>
----> 1 sla = businessDuration(startdate,enddate,starttime,endtime,holidaylist=holidaylist,unit=unit)
      2 sla

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\business_duration\__init__.py in businessDuration(startdate, enddate, starttime, endtime, weekendlist, holidaylist, unit)
     13     if starttime==None or endtime==None:
     14         return np.nan
---> 15     if pd.isnull(startdate) or pd.isnull(enddate) or startdate>enddate:
     16         return np.nan
     17     else:

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1535     @final
   1536     def __nonzero__(self):
-> 1537         raise ValueError(
   1538             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1539             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

If I understood the message, startdate and enddate are null for python, maybe because they are Pandas DataFrame type, and not datatime variables. But the pd.date_time does not change the type and should permit the calc operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `startdate` and `enddate` variables that you are passing to `businessDuration` are a `pandas.Series`.  You can see this by executing `type(startdate)`.

The `businessSeries` statement `startdate>enddate` (line 15) fails because Python cannot compare Series objects in this manner.

You can fix this by turning startdate and enddate into objects that can be compared.  You can add the following lines before calling `businessSerices`:

```
startdate = startdate.values[0]
enddate = enddate.values[0]
```

For a more elegant solution, you can look at simplifying the code you are using to set `startdate` and `enddate`.  `stack` and `to_datetime` may not be needed.